# Stream filter java works different with AND condition and brace

Tags: java

I have the below code that gives me completely different result in 1 vs 2. The expected result is only coming from 1 but not 2 and I can't seem to understand why. I wrote 2 to make it more readable.

```
myList.stream().filter(a -> a.getCity().equals("MEXICO") && a.mapStatus.equals("ERROR")).findFirst() ---> this is 1
myList.stream().filter(a -> (a.getCity().equals("MEXICO")) && (a.mapStatus.equals("ERROR"))).findFirst() --> this is 2
```

I am very new to using streams in Java. Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: I don't think adding brackets made it more readable.

Comment: The two statements are exactly the same when compiled.

Comment: This appear effectively identical. This is not a [mre].  Why do you think they are producing different answers?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here aren't the braces, its the fact that you changed `equals(MEXICO)` to `equals("MEXICO")`. The first uses the contents of the variable `MEXICO` to determine what the city should equal, the second just checks if the city is the literal string "MEXICO". They could do the same thing if the variable `MEXICO` actually also contains "MEXICO", but this is most likely not the case if it returns something else for you.

Comment: No that's not the problem. I was not able to edit my post but I have it as "MEXICO" in both places.

Comment: @rickygrimes then the only way your data could be different is if you have different data to begin with. both of these statements are exactly equal.